Firebase OTP SMS working on IOS but not on android. says 'unknown status code: 17499 BILLING_NOT_ENABLED'
I’m facing an issue where Firebase Authentication for phone verification works perfectly on iOS, but fails on Android with the following error message:
I/PlayCore(12548): UID: [10282]  PID: [12548] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=TAIswWqiEjMaLAH6-tOrTaGrMvhqeGJx-eoOAxAkGPM, cloudProjectNumber=551503664846, network=null})
I/PlayCore(12548): UID: [10282]  PID: [12548] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore(12548): UID: [10282]  PID: [12548] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})
I/PlayCore(12548): UID: [10282]  PID: [12548] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
I/PlayCore(12548): UID: [10282]  PID: [12548] OnRequestIntegrityTokenCallback : onRequestIntegrityToken
I/PlayCore(12548): UID: [10282]  PID: [12548] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.
W/System  (12548): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/BpBinder(12548): PerfMonitor binderTransact :  time=513ms interface=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.internal.ISmsRetrieverApiService code=1
E/FirebaseAuth(12548): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 BILLING_NOT_ENABLED
D/FirebaseAuth(12548): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +9779806090xxx, error - An internal error has occurred. [ BILLING_NOT_ENABLED ]


Environment:
Firebase: Authentication with Phone Sign-In
Platforms:
 iOS: Working fine

 Android: Fails with "BILLING_NOT_ENABLED"

On Android, the app is currently in debug mode and not distributed via the Play Store. Tested with release version and added a release version fingerprints as well on firebase.
The Firebase project is on the paid/blaze plan.

yes on blaze plan.
